# KivyMD create_project. How to get another screen by its name or id?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I created a KivyMD with "KivyMD create_project".
https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/api/kivymd/tools/patterns/create_project/index.html#module-kivymd.tools.patterns.create_project

I am trying to access other screens widgets ids but I realized that the screens does not have names or ids.

I tryed almost everything:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids returns empty ids {}
App.get_running_app().manager_screens.ids reeturns empty ids {}
App.get_running_app().manager_screens.get_screen('') tryed with "Home Screen", 
"Home_Screen", "HomeScreen", "home screen", "home_screen", "homescreen"
```

But no success.

Does anyone has any tips or workaround to get another screen widgets ids?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Should you be using this [command](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/api/kivymd/tools/patterns/create_project/index.html#create-project-with-responsive-view)?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Even if you give screen names in project building it is only for the class. It does not add a attribute name to call in manager_screens.get_screen('your_screen').